# Can I alias a column with an AS in the SELECT part of a MySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

Ive got a rather complicated query Im running, and before I change a table structure and rewrite some other files I was wondering if anyone could tell me if this is possible.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(users.user_id),
    (resi.curr_state WHERE resi.user_id = "users.user_id") AS current_state
FROM
    ci_users AS users, ci_residents AS resi .....
WHERE stuff HAVING current_state = '".$php_variable_ill_use."'
```

Im happy to share more code if necessary, but my main question here is can I do that first as statement before the from or even after if it will work.

Comment: warning. your code might be susceptible to sql injection.

Comment: That should word. The MySQL docs have some infos here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html

Comment: @hakre What? It should? The second column, as written, is syntactically incorrect, is it not?

Comment: At least that part isn't: `ci_residents AS resi .....` which is why I though the query is just a rough outline to illustrate the question and not an ask to fix the query.

Comment: ya, hakre is correct, im not worried about the rest of the query...or injection.  this is specifically asking about the as

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just run that query you post and see if it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work:

```
select distinct(users.user_id),
    (select resi.curr_state 
          from ci_residents 
            AS resi_1 where resi_1.user_id = users.user_id) as current_state
FROM
    ci_users AS users, ci_residents AS resi .....
WHERE stuff HAVING current_state = '".$php_variable_ill_use."'
```

Comment: oh wait nevermind yes it did thanks.  and thanks for actually answering THE QUESTION not commenting on what was clearly an example query.

Comment: @JohnB With all due respect, users at all levels of skill and experience use this site. It wasn't clear to me that you'd posted an example query, hence my comments and answer.

Comment: no worries sir.  i kind of overreacted because people only seem to misinterpret what I'm asking when I ask about mysql stuff  and I haven't had my coffee yet.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to conditionally specify the output of a column, yes: you use a `CASE` statement. But it doesn't look like that's what you're doing. You seem to be specifying a relationship between the `resi` and `users` tables, which you could normally accomplish using a JOIN, like this:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT(users.user_id),
    resi.curr_state AS current_state
FROM ci_users AS users
JOIN ci_residents AS resi ON users.user_id = resi.user_id
```

Now, given the logic behind your request, I assume you want *all* user_ids, but only those states where a state exists. Is that correct? If so, use a `LEFT JOIN` to include all `users` records, and include only `resi` records when an associated record exists.

Please elaborate if you're trying to accomplish something other than what I've illustrated here.

Comment: Basically, Im searching for members of a sight.  Along with a bunch of other conditions I didnt list, I need to add some to the tune of "WHERE place = state, and WHERE place = country, with state and country being entered as inputs by the user on the search form and both places being stored in the same table but assigned the same user_id